# How to get part of array excluding one key in multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm grouping one multidimensional array by age.

This is my code:

```
$mEmployees = array (
    array("name"=>"Pedro",  "age"=>20, "ID"=>1111), 
    array("name"=>"Carlos", "age"=>15, "ID"=>2222), 
    array("name"=>"Susana", "age"=>20, "ID"=>3333), 
    array("name"=>"Carmen", "age"=>19, "ID"=>4444)
);
$byAge=array();


foreach ($mEmployees as $k => $oneItem) {
   $byAge[$oneItem['age']][$k] = $oneItem;
}
var_dump($byAge);
```

That works fine as you can see below:

**output:**

```
array(3) {
  [20]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Pedro"
      ["age"]=>
      int(20)
      ["ID"]=>
      int(1111)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Susana"
      ["age"]=>
      int(20)
      ["ID"]=>
      int(3333)
    }
  }
  [15]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Carlos"
      ["age"]=>
      int(15)
      ["ID"]=>
      int(2222)
    }
  }
  [19]=>
  array(1) {
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Carmen"
      ["age"]=>
      int(19)
      ["ID"]=>
      int(4444)
    }
  }
}
```

But in the results, the `age` key is redundant. I want to remove this key in the `$byAge` array.

I tried with `array_slice`, but it's not possible to indicate one irregular offset (the key `age` is in middle).

How I can achieve this easily for this result?

```
array(3) {
  [20]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Pedro"
      ["ID"]=>
      int(1111)
    }
    [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Susana"
      ["ID"]=>
      int(3333)
    }
  }
  [15]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Carlos"
      ["ID"]=>
      int(2222)
    }
  }
  [19]=>
  array(1) {
    [3]=>
    array(3) {
      ["name"]=>
      string(6) "Carmen"
      ["ID"]=>
      int(4444)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cache the age value in a variable and unset from `$oneItem`.

```
foreach ($mEmployees as $k => $oneItem) {
   $age = $oneItem['age'];
   unset($oneItem['age']);
   $byAge[$age][$k] = $oneItem;
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/pDDn5